# Membercount command of all servers where the bot is in (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like a command that counts all users of every server the bot is in. However, with the code I have right now, the bot only counts per server.

```
if(message.content.startsWith("?membercount")) {
    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("**Bot Name**")
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .addField('Members', `**${message.guild.memberCount}**`, true)
    .addBlankField(true)
    .addField('Humans', `**${message.guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}**`, true)
    .addField('Bots', `**${message.guild.members.filter(member => member.user.bot).size}**`, true)
    .addField('Member Status', `**${message.guild.members.filter(o => o.presence.status === 'online').size}** Online\n**${message.guild.members.filter(i => i.presence.status === 'idle').size}** Inactive\n**${message.guild.members.filter(dnd => dnd.presence.status === 'dnd').size}** Do Not Disturb\n**${message.guild.members.filter(off => off.presence.status === 'offline').size}** Offline\n**${message.guild.members.filter(s => s.presence.status === 'streaming').size}** Streaming`)
    .setFooter(`© footername`)
  
    message.channel.send({embed});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the member count of all servers combined using `Collection.prototype.reduce()`

```
message.client.guilds.cache.map((g) => g.memberCount).reduce((a, c) => a + c)
```